# jQuery: Fetch Ajax to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I thought that the below shown code would work as a charm, but apparently it doesn't. I can't tell why it isnt working - The URL is fetched properly (checked with firebug) but it refuses to save the result to my variable (globalVar).

What can I do?

```
var globalVar;  

function fetchDataset(kategori){  

    $.getJSON(apiUrl + "?jsoncallback=?", function(json){
        globalVar = json;

        console.log(globalVar); // Returns Undefined!
    });


}
```

Comment: What is the content of the variable json?

Comment: Undefined! I understand Zip zero now!

Comment: Is the json is not well formed is fails silently, e.g. { a: 1 } needs to be { "a": 1  }. Get your JSON in order! :)

Comment: @mattcodes: Afraid that that isn't the issue - JSONlint says my JSON is valid...

Comment: Hmm.. I had exactly the same issue today as getJSON will silently fail if JSON is not strictly valid - check mime returned from server too. So change to $.ajax(type: 'get', success:function, error: function(crap) { alert(crap); } so we can see what the problem is

Comment: Yep - even the headers in my requested page is set to JSON and firebug are able to download it completely :(

Comment: @mattcodes - Error nor success callback functions are happening, though firebug still seeing the JSON

Comment: You could try console.log(globalVar.toSource()) instead of console.log(globalVar). BTW: Why does your URL end with "?"? I think this is not recommended...

Comment: Hi! That didn't work either. Read here about the URL GET tag, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ : "If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, nothing worked, so I instead ending up making a PHP-based proxy that tunnels any cross-domain request. After changing the url to the PHP proxy, it worked great.

Thanks for everyones help. Very appreciated!

Comment: You didnt say it was cross domain! As far as I know that means you have to use a script tag rather than a ajax request and as getJSON fails silently herein lies your problem!

Comment: How you mean with script tag?

Comment: I assumed that JSONP would work with cross-domain requests as shown on the jQuery website hence why I didn't write about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess firebug should display the contents of your callback. I had a similar problem and solved it using .parseJSON();

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Maybe it helps.

Is the callback neatly formatted/"correct" json?

Comment: Hi Adam - can you show me how you solved it with parseJSON? It appears that nothing is shown from the callback actually...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not global. You defined it within the scope of the function. Your Ajax call is run asynchronously which means that your function will complete (probably) before the ajax request is returned. Try declaring globalVar outside of the function. ie.

```
var globalVar;    
function fetchDataset(kategori){
```

**Edit:** Also, check the `statusText` (second variable passed to the callback function) to make sure that there are no errors with your request.

Comment: Hi! That was an oversight of me - the globalVar is already declared outside the function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Drackir - it appears that nothing is actually happening inside the callback. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Industrial: Perhaps try getting the third argument of the callback (the xmlhttprequest object) and checking what the `returnText` property equals.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making a cross domain request?

If so make sure you use jsonp

> JSONP
>   If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

There is an example here of jsonp.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Yep - cross domain - the request is properly completed according to FireBug, but only undefined in the script.

Comment: Yep that fine but getJSON wont inject a script tag. so just appending callback=? isnt sufficient for cross domain.